# Dynamically change to Listview frm Gridview

Tags: android, listview, gridview, fragment

i want to change view frm gridview to listview after view gets clicked by user in a Fragment.

But i am not being able to do that .
Searched a lot on google Quora and SO but didnt finad any solution

Here is my Fragment code

```
public class FragmentAlbum extends Fragment  {

@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.album,container, false);


    activity = getActivity();
        lv=(GridView) root.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        lv.setAdapter(adaptor);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

          root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.album_list,container, false);
         listview=(ListView) root.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

                  listview.setAdapter(adaptor1);    
                  break;

         }

             }}
);

        return root;
}
```

.
When i click view remains in Gridview
initial view doesnt goes off.

album is gridview layout.

album_list is listview layout.

i am not getting any error but logically its not working.

Can  anyone suggest me my mistake?.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use recyclerview for this.

Set layoutmanager as gridlayout manager for gridview and linearlayout manager for listview.

use your logics according to conditions.

Comment: Heyy @Shashank Garg can you tell me that how can I change layouts in the gridview. I mean to say that I have different layout for gridview and listview.

Answer (score 2):

One option available to you is to use a GridView and change the number of columns dynamically depending on state. GridView has a numColumns property which you can change at runtime and then apply by calling notifyDataSetChanged on your adapter.

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837780/android-set-the-gridview-to-have-2-columns-per-row-only

Comment: I was looking to point you in the right direction instead of doing the work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `RecyclerView` and change the `ListView` to `GridView` based on your column count like following, this is very easy while compared to other posts.

```
private void setLayoutManager() {
    if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
        mColumnCount = 1;
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    } else {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the GridView-style to ListView-style and ListView-style to GridView progamatically. Then just change the NO-OF-COLUMNS value of gridview programmatically .
Like here

```
  switchIV.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {

            if(style==0)
            {

                //Change gridview to listview style
                gridview.setNumColumns(1);
                Update_with_ListView_Style();
                style=1;

            }
            else
            {
                //change gridview back to gridview style with 3 columns
                gridview.setNumColumns(3);
                 Update_with_GridView_Style();
                 style=0;

            }
        }

    });
```